# Long page in Firefox truncated

Tags: html, firefox

One of the pages on my website is pretty tall.  It's under 200KB in size, but it's a series of tables that takes a lot of vertical space.  After about 40 screenfuls (about 1/4 of the total scrolling height of the webpage), it just stops drawing: everything above that looks fine, and everything below that is plain white background -- except the footer (in a different div, I guess), which shows up fine at the very bottom.

I've asked around the office, and other people have seen this before, but don't know what causes it.  We certainly have other pages here that are just as tall, and have no problem.  I've seen pages render fine which are much longer.  It's not a complex document at all -- some nested divs, some tables (4 or 5 columns, a couple hundred rows each), some CSS.

The page renders great in both IE7 and Chrome.  Only Firefox 3 does this.

Any clues as to what's causing this?  Or a workaround?  I don't even know what to google for here.

EDIT: I've seen this on another, completely unrelated page.  In both cases, it cuts off at about 33000 px from the top -- ha.  I know FF3 can have divs and tables longer than that.  Anybody know what they might be using a 16-bit size/coordinate for?

Comment: perhaps ask yourself why are you displaying that much data to a user at one time? Who would need, muchless be able to consume, that much data at one time?

Comment: @Malfist: that's beside the point, isn't it?

Comment: Not entirely, but that's why I didn't post it as an answer. It is still a valid point though.

Comment: I encountered the same behaviour a few times, only the background was black ... in different forums and such. FF305

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this may be related to [Firefox Bug 215055](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215055) or [Firefox Bug 333994](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333994).  Check these out.  If it is indeed related, you can always attach your testcase to one of these bugs and add your comments to the bug.

I also recommend, like zodeus does, trying a nightly build or a beta of 3.1.  If it's fixed there, that doesn't mean you force your customers to upgrade, but at least you know it's fixed in a future build and you can campaign for Mozilla.org to bring the fix back to a more current build where you might get people to upgrade.

Comment: We have a winner!  It does look like #215055: removing an overflow:auto fixed it.  Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the Fire Fox 3.1 Beta or Nightly Build. They have reworked a lot of their internals. If it works there then I would say it's a reported and fixed FF3.0 bug.

Comment: Great, but it doesn't help me.  If I could get 100% of my customers to upgrade to a beta browser just because I asked them nicely, I'd have already told them to get Chrome.  :-)

Comment: Welcome to the world of multiple browser support. Is there any chance of pagination. With a bit of ajax the user experience could remain almost identical. E.g. as you scroll down the page you unload the data above and load in new data blow.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418600) bug filed in Bugzilla may be related...

Comment: Hmm.  Doesn't look like it.  His test case works fine here.  And I'm seeing text, images, and everything disappear -- not just background overflowing.  (My table and page background are both white, so that might not affect me anyway.)